# Better data type to store a long ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, types, numeric

I'm working on a project using Rails. In this app, we use OAuth to enable Facebook and Google sign-up/log-in. I want to store the various providers (FB or Google) and user IDs associated with these providers in a separate table/model that will be related to the user.

My question is the next one, the user IDs provided by FB and Google are really long numbers (Google's is 21 digits). Would it make sense to store it as an integer or better store it as a string? Which are the pros-cons of those two options?

I'm using Postgres 10.14.

Comment: This will largely wind up a opinions, For mine store them as a string. Your values are coming from a external source over which you have no control and I would suggest you are not calculating anything with them. Can you ensure that you will never allow another source that uses an alphanumeric scheme.

Comment: @Belayer: While assuming the number is all digits (and probably coding on that assumption) I would not want other characters to creep in secretly, so no string type. I would want an immediate error message if that should happen. The first question: is it reasonable to assume all digits?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter:  That is why I said it would wind up being largely opinions. Agreed, I would not want character values to creep in, but without control I cannot prevent characters from intentionally being put there. So as to your first question - No, but from a universe of 2 neither is it reasonable to assume it must be all digits.  So my first question is slightly different: is it reasonable to assume they *must* be all digits.  If I want to validate data from multiple external entities, that I cannot dictate the data formats, then I need different validation routines for each.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot store that many digits in a Postgres integer column. `bigint` allows a maximum of 19 digits (9223372036854775801 being the biggest positive number: `2^63-1`).

While the number is all **digits**, the most efficient, **exact** data type is [`numeric`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html). The manual:

> The actual storage requirement is two bytes for each group of four decimal digits, plus three to eight bytes overhead.

21 decimal digits stored as `numeric` will occupy 18 bytes in RAM and 15 bytes on disk. See:

- [What is the overhead for varchar(n)?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/125526/3684)
- [Lookup performance of Numeric vs String](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/193290/3684)